Python debugger raising ModuleNotFoundError when module is imported
I am trying to use the python debugger in VSCode as there are errors when running my script that I am trying to resolve, however whenever I run the debugger it raises a ModuleNotFoundError for pandas which I have installed.
When I run the script by itself there is no ModuleNotFoundError, and I can print pandas DataFrames to show that pandas is definitely installed and imported when I run the script. So, I am not sure what is different about when the debugger runs that it can't find the pandas module.

Please edit your question to include a reproducible example of your code.
